# Missing Detail in Construction of Étale Fundamental Group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}$I am currently trying to consolidate my understanding of the étale fundamental group, and there is a small detail in the construction that I do not understand in general. While I can see why this occurs for most particular examples, my arguments are quite ad hoc and do not give me insight into the wider problem.

Given a pro-representing system $\tilde X = (X_i)_{i \in I}$ for the functor which takes lifts of a geometric point, I do not understand why we get induced maps $\Aut_X(X_j) \to \Aut_X(X_i)$. This is quite important because one possible definition of the étale fundamental group is $\pi_1(X, \overline{x}) \mathrel{:=} \varprojlim \Aut_X(X_i)$. My topological intuition tells me that there is probably some sort of Lifting Criterion-style argument here, but I cannot fill in the gaps.

Comment: I think you have to be careful with the pro-system you choose. Consider the case where $X = \operatorname{Spec} k$ where $k$ is a field such as $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{F}_q$. The choice of a geometric point and lifts of it correspond to the choice of an algebraic closure and embeddings into it. The obvious choice of pro-system is to take all finite extensions of $k$, but you can’t always restrict an automorphism of one field extension to a subextension – this is the whole point of the notion of normal extensions! So you have to discard non-normal extensions from your pro-system.

Comment: That's a good point. The collection of all Galois finite etale coverings (wtih appropriately chosen morphisms between them) is a pro-representing system for our functor, so we can arrange to avoid this problem.